# How can I add dynamic placeholder text to angular-google-maps autocomplete form?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I'm building a route-planning app using the angular-google-maps module and can't find a way to add dynamic placeholder text to an autocomplete form on the edit page.

Here's my code.

In the JS controller:

```
    var startpointEvents = {
    places_changed: function (searchBox) {
      var place = searchBox.getPlaces();
      startpoint = place[0];
      if (!place[0].geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  self.startpointSearchbox = { 
    template:'js/views/searchboxes/startpointSearchbox.tpl.html', 
    events: startpointEvents,
    parentdiv: "startpoint-input"
  };

  var endpointEvents = {
    places_changed: function (searchBox) {
      var place = searchBox.getPlaces();
      endpoint = place[0];

      if (!place[0].geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  self.endpointSearchbox = { 
    template:'js/views/searchboxes/endpointSearchbox.tpl.html', 
    events: endpointEvents,
    parentdiv: "endpoint-input"
  };

  var stopoverEvents = {
    places_changed: function (searchBox) {
      var place = searchBox.getPlaces();
      stopover.push(place[0]);
      console.log(stopover);
      if (!place[0].geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  self.stopoverSearchbox = { 
    template:'js/views/searchboxes/stopoverSearchbox.tpl.html', 
    events: stopoverEvents,
    parentdiv: "stopover-input"
  };
```

In the HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar-content">

        <h2 class="trip-name-head">{{ trips.trip.name }} trip</h2>

      <form class="form" id="tripForm" ng-submit="trips.updateTrip()">
        <div id="startpoint-input">

        </div>
        <div id="endpoint-input">

        </div>
        <div id="stopover-input">

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit" class="save-button">
      </form>
    </div>   

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='trips.map.center' zoom='trips.map.zoom'>
      <!-- look for configuration (template, events and parentdiv) defined in tripsController -->
      <ui-gmap-search-box template="trips.startpointSearchbox.template" events="trips.startpointSearchbox.events" parentdiv="trips.startpointSearchbox.parentdiv"></ui-gmap-search-box>

      <ui-gmap-search-box template="trips.endpointSearchbox.template" events="trips.endpointSearchbox.events" parentdiv="trips.endpointSearchbox.parentdiv"></ui-gmap-search-box>

      <ui-gmap-search-box template="trips.stopoverSearchbox.template" events="trips.stopoverSearchbox.events" parentdiv="trips.stopoverSearchbox.parentdiv"></ui-gmap-search-box>

      <ui-gmap-search-box template="trips.stopoverSearchbox.template" events="trips.stopoverSearchbox.events" parentdiv="trips.stopoverSearchbox.parentdiv"></ui-gmap-search-box>

      <ui-gmap-search-box template="trips.stopoverSearchbox.template" events="trips.stopoverSearchbox.events" parentdiv="trips.stopoverSearchbox.parentdiv"></ui-gmap-search-box>

      <ui-gmap-search-box template="trips.stopoverSearchbox.template" events="trips.stopoverSearchbox.events" parentdiv="trips.stopoverSearchbox.parentdiv"></ui-gmap-search-box>

      <ui-gmap-markers models="trips.markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'"></ui-gmap-markers>

      <ui-gmap-polyline ng-repeat="p in trips.polylines track by $index" path="p.path" stroke="p.stroke" visible='p.visible' geodesic='p.geodesic' fit="false" editable="p.editable" draggable="p.draggable" icons='p.icons'></ui-gmap-polyline>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

My templates:

```
<input id="startpoint-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="{{ trips.boundcontent }}">

<input id="endpoint-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="{{ trips.boundcontent }}">

<input id="stopover-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="{{ trips.boundcontent }}">
```

The boundcontent in the placeholder attribute won't pick anything up from the trips controller. Is this possible with angular-google-maps?

Thanks in advance